# what is actual implementation of lua __pairs?

Tags: lua, metatable, lua-5.2, meta-method

Does anybody know actual implementation of lua 5.2. metamethod `__pairs`? In other words, how do I implement `__pairs` as a metamethod in a metatable so that it works exactly same with `pairs()`?

I need to override `__pairs` and want to skip some dummy variables that I add in a table.

Comment: http://lua-users.org/wiki/GeneralizedPairsAndIpairs

Answer (score 4):

The following would use the metatable meta to explicitly provide `pairs` default behavior:

```
function meta.__pairs(t)
  return next, t, nil
end
```

Now, for skipping specific elements, we must replace the returned `next`:

```
function meta.__pairs(t)
  return function(t, k)
    local v
    repeat
      k, v = next(t, k)
    until k == nil or theseok(t, k, v)
    return k, v
  end, t, nil
end
```

For reference: [Lua 5.2 manual, pairs](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-pairs)

Answer (score 1):

The code below skips some entries. Adapt as needed.

```
local m={
January=31, February=28, March=31, April=30, May=31, June=30,
July=31, August=31, September=30, October=31, November=30, December=31,
}

setmetatable(m,{__pairs=
function (t)
    local k=nil
    return
    function ()
        local v
        repeat k,v=next(t,k) until v==31 or k==nil
        return k,v
    end
end})

for k,v in pairs(m) do print(k,v) end
```

Comment: `v` should be a local. Also, it diverges from the default `pairs` much more than needed.