# Lua - implement userdata iterator

Tags: lua, lua-userdata

Lua 5.2
I need to iterate an `userdata` variable.
As I understand, I can do this using `getmetatable` and `__pairs`. Like this:

```lua
for k, v in getmetatable(userdataVariable).__pairs do
  -- someting
end
```

But I get 'attempt to call a nil value' when I'm trying to do this.

I found a `__pairs` implementation here: [what is actual implementation of lua __pairs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23624248/what-is-actual-implementation-of-lua-pairs)

```lua
function meta.__pairs(t)
  return function(t, k)
    local v
    repeat
      k, v = next(t, k)
    until k == nil or theseok(t, k, v)
    return k, v
  end, t, nil
end
```

But I don't understand what I should do with `theseok`? What function should I define here?

Comment: I don't think you need it, actually. [And take a look here](https://github.com/ThePhD/sol2/issues/146)

Answer (score -1):

I think you're looking for the `__index` meta table.